# SXA trim titles in variant

Tags: sxa

I have a variant that will display the item title, is there a way that i can trim the title from front end?

Is there any attributes or properties in the variant field to trim title from the variant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. All you need to do is to use `VariantTemplate` and do something like that:

[image]

Comment: I will have to create custom method for trim or is it available out of the box in SXA?

Comment: I will work out of the box in the NVelocity template as I shown above.